# Push Notification sleep time with parse.com

Tags: ios, parse-platform, push-notification

I want to send push notifications to an iOS app via parse.com, but not during a "sleep time" that the user should be able to configure in my app.

Is there a way to filter the audience by current time in their timezone, depending on start and end times?

Comment: Are you uploading the details to the installation? How are you triggering the send?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "uploading the details to the installation". Send is triggered via the REST Api.

Comment: Each device is stored as an installation, and you can choose a group of installations to send a push to.

Comment: Right, I am looking for a way to set a "sleep time start" and "sleep time end" time value in the installation that I then can filter on when sending. Couldn't figure out a way to do that yet.

Comment: Add the columns, you can specify less than and greater than dates on the query

Comment: As far as I can see you can only add datetime columns, but I need timestamps. Did I overlook something? Thanks!

Comment: They're the same thing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95907/discussion-between-cornelius-and-wain).